# I already a expo app published on play and apple store. How can I use a OTA over-the-air update in this case?

Tags: react-native, expo, code-push, over-the-air

Like I said in subtitle, I already a expo app published on play and apple store. Expo version 37.0.0.

I would like use OTA updates, but I don't know how to do this.

In Expo documentation, I need upgrade to 37.0.2 version to use expo-updates. And import on app.js and use a useEffect function to start use the expo-updates.

That is okay, but, how can I do this and linking this code with the apk/ipa that is already published on stores? Is that possible?

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand - your best solution will be to do the new "classic" release with all the necessary changes for OTA usage and then use it.

There is a good [explanation](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-managed-workflow-in-2021-5b887bbf7dbb) (video included) from the expo developer